# Subversion failing to find correct repo location

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

I just updated my version of eclipse to Juno and installed svn but every time I try to enter my existing repo location I get an error. Looking at the error it appending the local eclipse directory into the file path. This is the path that the error is giving "**'U:\eclipse\file:\U:\svnRepo' is not a working copy**" though I am only entering the

```
 file:\\\U:\svnRepo
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Subclipse or Subversive? Is that not one backslash to much behind the file:\\ ?

Comment: Subversive and no it requires the 3 backslashes (I believe that the first one is an escape character?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten around the problem by renaming the existing repo to "OLD_svnRepo", creating a new directory "svnRepo", creating a new repo location and pointing to the new folder. I can then import and point to the existing repo and everything is good.

While I think this is an acceptable solution (because it gets me back up and coding instead of playing around with eclipse) I would like to know if there is a bug in the Juno package/Subversive so that I do not have to play around every time I do a fresh install.